# What do you call someone who's obsessed with the latest equipment/gear/products?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

"Hypebeast" is **not** the word I am looking for, as I would associate a "hypebeast" as someone obsessed with frivolous possessions like overpriced brand-name clothing and fashion in general.

I need a more generalized word/phrase that would describe somebody who cares about the latest technologies, equipment, products, etc.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps *tech-savvy* or *techie/techy*?

Comment: perhaps an early adopter

Comment: Is it just for the sake of having the latest / best gear? Or do they generally use it as well? As "all the gear, no idea" springs to mind, if they have Everest grade hiking gear to go for a walk in the woods for example.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [technophile](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/technophile) for someone who is attracted to shiny new technological things.

It's opposite would be [technophobe](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/technophobe).

Comment: Somewhat offtopic, I dislike the idea of referring to technophobes as if they have a phobia. It's hardly ever an _irrational fear_ of technology, and more often its only an _inability to easily adopt it_.

Answer (score 0):

"Somebody who cares about the latest technologies, equipment, products, etc" (as a consumer) is the direction in which the word **geek** seems to be evolving (by contrast to **nerd**).

See: [Which term correctly identifies those who enjoy programming/technology: "geek" or "nerd"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4823/which-term-correctly-identifies-those-who-enjoy-programming-technology-geek-o)